# How do I validate a cell using a range from a ListObject in Excel?

Tags: excel, validation, vba, listobject

I'm trying to validate a cell (*List* type validation) using values in a row that is in ListObject.  When I use a *named range* in my validation code, it works; but if I replace the *named range* reference to a *ListObject* reference it throws an error.

Can you use a ListObject to validate a cell?

This is what I am doing that works using a *named range*:

```
With Range("Table1[COL1]").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="=DEPT_NAMES" ' where DEPT_NAMES is a manually created named range
    '[...] more stuff goes here
End With
```

But if I replace the value of `Formula1:=` and have it point to a valid list object like this:

```
Formula1:="=Table2[COL2]"
```

... I get an error.  I've also tried doing this through the UI and it doesn't work.

Can you really not validate a cell using a ListObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.  I think a two-step process will work for you:

1. Create a named range defined as `"=Table2[ROW2]"`
2. Point your data validation list at that named range.

This works for me in Excel 2010.  The data validation list shrinks and grows with the insertion and deletion of table rows.

I'm a little confused by the name "Table2[ROW2]."  A column would make more sense both in terms of Tables/Listobjects and data validation.

Comment: This was **exactly** what I needed!  Thank you!  PS - I fixed the made-up variables to reflect columns rather than rows in my post.  Was just quick typing out my ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found somewhere else (https://blackatlascreative.com/blog/create-an-excel-data-validation-list-using-a-table/):

```
Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""Table2[COL2]"")"
```

The addition of `INDIRECT` is the key difference.